# Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a $\pi$-system. May we partition any $A\in\sigma(\mathcal{I})$ into a countable collection of subsets $A_k$ of $\mathcal{I}$?

Tags: measure-theory

I've been wondering if the statment below is true, although I've been stuck for a while trying to prove it either true or false and thus I'd appreciate a hand (:

---

Let $X$ be an arbitrary non-empty set.

**Definition 1:** A $\pi$-system is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ closed under finite intersections.

**Definition 2:** given $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, we define $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ i.e. the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{A}$.

**Hypothesis:** Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a $\pi$-system. For any $A\in \sigma(\mathcal{I})$ we may find a countable cover $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots \}\subseteq \mathcal{I}$ of $A$ such that
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k = A.$$

---

***Question:*** is the hypothesis correct? If so, how could it be proven. If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: To disprove the hypothesis, how about $X = \{0, 1\}, \mathcal{A} = \{\{0\}\}, A = X$?

Comment: A more profound result/counterexample is: even if $\mathcal{A}$ itself is a $\sigma$-algebra, you still cannot represent every set in $\mathcal{A}$ by repeated finite and countable set-theoretic operations starting with sets in $\mathcal{A}$.   The construction is much more difficult:  see *Probability and Measure*, pp. 30 -- 32.